# Chain methods on rxjava

Tags: rx-java

How to call a method after realizing all other methods have been done. all the methods are having observables.

```
Observable.just(""
    )
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: loading config");
            loadConfiguration();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onNext: loading data");
            initOperatorData();
            initCompanyData();
            initVehicleData();
            initToolsData();
        }
    });

private void initCompanyData() {
    Subscription subscription = db.loadDataMaster()
            .map(new Func1<RealmResults<DataMaster>, List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String> call(RealmResults<DataMaster> dataMasters) {
                    List<String> companies = getCompanyNames(dataMasters);
                    return companies;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<String> companyNames) {
                    setCompanyNames(companyNames);
                }
            });}
```

I want to call the observables on those methods on "onNext" once they all finish, I call the one in onComplete. but this does not happen because they all async. onComplete happens before initToolsData.

Is there a way to chain calls to methods asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all your `init*` and `loadConfiguration` methods return `Observable`.

In this case, you can `merge` all `Oservable` then `concatWith` your another `Observable`, created from `loadConfiguration`

```
 Observable.merge(initOperatorData(), initCompanyData(), initVehicleData(), initToolsData())
           // I force to cast to Object otherwise, it may not compile, dependings of your methods signatures
           .cast(Object.class)
           // you'll subscribe to loadConfiguration when all previous Observable will be completed
           .concatwith(loadConfiguration())
           .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the method implementation. I have a subscription already in each method where I set some data. What could be the solution for that as merge needs observables

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to simplify (and excuse the Java 8, it makes logic much more reasonable):

```
Observable.merge(
        initOperatorData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        initCompanyData() .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        initVehicleData() .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        initToolsData()   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
.ignoreElements()
.doOnComplete(() -> loadConfiguration())
.toBlocking()
.subscribe();

private Observable<?> initCompanyData() {
    return db
        .loadDataMaster()
        .doOnNext(dataMasters -> setCompanyNames(getCompanyNames(dataMasters)));
}
```

Much more comprehensible, don't you say? BTW, if you don't need to wait for completion of the `loadConfiguration()` method, you can omit the `.toBlocking()` call. Also, you should use the `computation()` scheduler if you intend to run this on phones with less than 4 cores.